# How do I choose between ‘who’ or ‘whom’ when the subject pronoun is unclear?

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns, whom, who

**A friend needs help with his *who* and *whom***

Right on the heels of my recent [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397966/why-do-so-many-people-struggle-with-who-and-whom) regarding *why* 'who' and 'whom' present difficulties for so many native and non-native learners, comes another complex case of ‘who’ and ‘whom’.

The language of a friend's report is bureaucratically complicated and his Supervising Teacher, is *very* pedantic that the English should be absolutely grammatically correct, **which includes the prescriptive use of ‘who’ and ‘whom’.**

This means that the excellent generic advice

> **“use *who* in every case and always avoid *whom*”**

cannot, unfortunately, be applied here. Many grammatically pedantic non-native teachers in my country insist on the proper use of 'whom', especially in official reports and dissertations.

My friend therefore needs a reliable practical approach (that can be applied in any given case) to decide whether 'who' or 'whom' should be employed in a particular situation.

---

**When does it get complicated?**

Problems arise when the sentence does not obviously require a subject pronoun, and the concerned verb is moreover not obviously transitive, making it difficult to decide whether it needs an object pronoun. Again, when the sentence has multiple verbs and clauses, where does one look for an indication as to whether it needs a subject pronoun or an object pronoun?

---

***Appendix: Example sentences from my friend's report***

I have extracted one relevant passage to better illustrate the problem. N.B **this is not a request for proofreading.**

> "A study of employee expectations regarding future confirmation in Government service, with special emphasis on the ethical aspects in the subjects' claim that long-term provisional employment is a virtual promise of future confirmation":

> This special short project conducted a detailed case study of 5 typical auxiliary health care workers **who(m)** the Government has instructed Heads of Department to terminate from long-standing provisional employment.

> The Department of Public Health had allotted special allowances for all subjects **who(m)** the Supervising Teacher considered deserving of compensatory remuneration for their time and effort spent participating in this project.

> Mr.A, **who(m)** the academic committee had originally advised against, was however selected as the 5th subject due to a lack of other 'typical' cases.

> The Supervising Teacher Mrs.B later raised an objection regarding payment of the special allowance to Mr.A, **who(m)** she had expressed reservations about in writing, leading to his initial disqualification by the academic committee, although he was subsequently selected and did actually participate as a subject of the study.

> The Head of the Accounts Department delivered the official opinion that a person **who(m)** the Supervising Teacher had specifically shown a reluctance towards nominating as a subject of the study could not be considered for the award of any special allowance.

Comment: It appears to me that in all those cases *who/whom* is an object pronoun, because it refers to the object of its clause.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346055/which-is-right-they-are-who-whom-we-dislike

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Leach -- object pronoun in all these cases is what I thought myself, and would recommend the use of 'whom' because the teacher does not like to see 'who' where the 'rule' insists on 'whom.'

Comment: What is with the recent spate in questions about *whom*?

Comment: @Dan Bron 'whom' is not dead or even moribund among non-native speakers of English, is what it means! Many of our more senior teachers don't like to see 'who' when the 'rule' calls for 'whom.'

Comment: @EnglishStudent Then shouldn't they be telling you the rule they insist upon rather than vice-versa?

Comment: @English Student: As [the top-rated answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/94/2637) to the earlier question on this point says: *Short answer: When in doubt, use **who.*** But if you're determined to swim against the tide regarding modern use of English, the slightly longer answer is to consider which ***pronoun*** you would use to identify the referent of ***who/whom***. Contrast, for example, ***Whom** did you see? I saw **him,*** and ***Who** saw you? **He** saw me.*

Comment: @EnglishStudent I've now read your Q in more detail: why can't you go post your prospective answer on the exact duplicate? Why do we need another question on this topic? As for a simple algorithm, why is the "pronoun test" insufficient? Can your audience not internalize "he -> who, him -> whom"?

Comment: @@English Student: I appreciate that non-native speakers face a particular problem in this area *if they have to pass exams*, because what they're being taught (and are expected to regurgitate in the exam room) is increasingly out of step with what native speakers actually *say*. One other useful short-cut is to note that about the only surviving context where significant numbers of native speakers still use ***whom*** is *after a preposition (**to, for, by**)*. You can exemplify those with ***For whom** the Bell Tolls* and ***To whom** am I speaking?*

Comment: @EnglishStudent If you say so, I believe you. Go post your prospective answer on the exact dupe.

Comment: @EnglishStudent The reality is no, it won't, but that doesn't give us license to *knowingly* ask and answer a duplicate question rather than aggregate all knowledge under one heading, in the service of our useless, old, new, and future. To do otherwise would be corrupt. You may open Meta question to attract attention and edits to your new answer.

Comment: If you want to make a question longish like this, you want to give it headings. I'll come back and read it if you do. Just ping me back after you've done it. I've pinged @Mari-LouA into this comment too, because she thinks perhaps your question's re-openable. (It might be, but you'd have to reformat otherwise who's going to read it thisnlong? And then who's going to write you an answer for a question that's so long - without clearly sign-posted subheadings?)

Comment: I agree with @AndrewLeach that in all of those sentences it looks like an object pronoun, so I think your suggested rule would apply as usual (whom in all cases).  I think to get people to reopen the question, you could present an argument for why these cases might use *who*, which could then open up the possibility of a nuanced answer that wouldn't fit on the other question marked duplicate.  I would focus on the last sentence, since it's the only one where the noun being replaced by  "who(m)" performs an action ("a *person* who(m)... could not be considered")

Comment: @EnglishStudent - I suggest you place a bounty on the question to give visibility.

Comment: @Josh thank you for casting a binding vote to reopen this question!

Comment: Telling people to only use "who" is not excellent advice, it is lazy and pathetic and not worthy of any English teacher.

Comment: @Jez you say _*Telling people to only use "who" is not excellent advice, it is lazy and pathetic and not worthy of any English teacher* _  it's considered safe advice because it's true that 'whom' used in the wrong place looks worse than 'who': but I agree that as a method it is too easy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, each of the examples given in the body of your question should be "whom."

This is a holdover from when the English language had cases, which you sort of referenced by noting the difficulty in identifying a subject. **Who** is always a subject, while *whom* is either a direct object, indirect object, or object of preposition:

1) Whom did you kill? (DO)
2) To whom did you give the book? (IO)
3) Who is the person about whom you are talking? (ObjP)

If it is difficult to tell by looking at the original sentence, try moving the who/whom in the sentence to see whether it holds an object position:

1) ...the Government has instructed Heads of Department to terminate **whom** from long-standing provisional employment.

2)...the Supervising Teacher considered **whom** deserving of compensatory remuneration...

3)...the academic committee had originally advised against **whom**...

4)...she had expressed reservations about **whom** in writing...

5)...the Supervising Teacher had specifically shown a reluctance towards nominating **whom**...

It may initially feel weird performing this kind of move operation, but if you can't immediately see whether the who/whom is acting as an object or not, then this is the easiest way to disambiguate that.

Comment: I like your point "try moving the who/whom in the sentence to see whether it holds an object position" -- thank you for answering the question and suggesting one simple method to decide whether the sentence takes an object pronoun.

Comment: Please note that I have accepted your excellent answer to make sure it comes right next to the question, as it contains a very good method for learners to use to decide correctly upon (whether to use) who or whom; but I have awarded the bounty to John Lawler's grammatically more detailed answer which clarified my own concept of this topic. Many thanks for your contribution towards improving my understanding of who and whom!

Answer (score 6):

Relative pronouns like *who, which,* etc. are extracted from some position in the relative clause and moved to the front of the clause.
I.e,

- *the car [**which** she saw ___ in the street]*
  starts with a clause that modifies a noun phrase *the car*,
  that **contains** a noun phrase *the car* --
    *the car [she saw **the car** in the street]*
  then *the car* is changed to a relative pronoun (*which*), and moved to the front of the clause,
  leaving a conceptual gap (____) in the clause showing the original position of the NP.

That's the way it works in all cases, except for the case in which the NP is the subject of the clause. There's no movement then, because the subject is already at the beginning of the sentence; it just needs to be changed to a relative pronoun and we're done.
I.e,

- *the dog [**which** barked in the night]*
  comes from
  *the dog [**the dog** barked in the night]*
  and we're done. No movement, no gap.

*Who* and *whom* work the same way as *which*, **but** there's a complication.

Since Relative Formation is an unbounded extraction rule, the relativized noun phrase can come from **any** part of the relative clause, no matter how many subordinate clauses it has. That means the gap is not always easy to find, especially for a non-native speaker.
E.g, the relativized NP can be the subject,

- *the man [**the man** told me yesterday the FBI was after him]*
  ==>
  *the man [**who** told me yesterday the FBI was after him]*

but it can also be the object of a preposition several levels down

- *the man [the FBI told me yesterday they were after **the man**]*
  ==>
  *the man [**whom** the FBI told me yesterday they were after ____]*.

In fact, it can be arbitrarily far down, and may be the subject of a predicate in another clause.

- *the man [the FBI told me Mary said she thought **the man** was guilty]*
  ==>
  *the man [**who** the FBI told me Mary said she thought ____ was guilty]*.
  (*whom* is incorrect here because *the man* is the subject of *was guilty*)

When there is a preposition involved (as with *advise against* and *reservations about*), then [Pied-Piping](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55129/15299) the preposition along with the relative pronoun can be employed to muddy the waters even further; it's an optional rule, but it can be employed whenever the relative pronoun is a prepositional object. This is the only construction in English that actually **requires** *whom*
(though, since pied-piping is optional, *whom* is still never required; just avoid pied-piping).
Viz.

- *Mr.A, **against whom** the academic committee had originally advised,*
- *Mr.A, **about whom** she had expressed reservations in writing,*

Executive summary: Find that gap, test it with *he/him*, and pied-pipe all prepositions.

Comment: Thank you @John Lawler for the detailed and illuminating answer that helped me (finally) understand the workings of *which, who and whom.* It is very kind of you -- especially considering your expert opinion that 'whom' is never required -- and I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Did @Engl actually read the answer? Lawler concedes that there is a context in which *who* cannot substitute for *whom*.

Comment: @Clare yes indeed: so you will like to know that John Lawler has explicitly made this point that there is never a need to use 'whom' in an answer as well: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111442/231519 In case you disagree, you could help me a lot by posting your own answer to this question.

Comment: Great! I wonder which answer were supposed to believe. Which one do you believe?

Comment: @Clare It is my personal opinion that 'whom' needs to be used where appropriate, but it is also true that the English speaking world is increasingly using 'who' for 'whom' -- I shall refer your question to John Lawler who, having posted this answer here, is the best person to explain this point.

Comment: @Clare: The only context in which _whom_ is required is when it follows, and is the object of, a preposition. This is the context produced by pied-piping. However, pied-piping is always optional (like _whom_, outside a prepositional phrase), so it's still true that one never **needs** to use _whom_, unless one wishes to. The OP apparently wishes to, and pied-piping will make _whom_ even more stuffy. The problem is always going to be finding that gap; it takes a lot of skill to anticipate the grammatical structure of something you haven't said yet.

Comment: +1 Though it's a bit like watching a therapist show someone how to walk with a limp.;)

Comment: Yeah, well, that's what drama coaches are for.

Answer (score 2):

The ‘simple’ substitution of *he/him* to determine whether to use who/whom does not always work for more complex sentences, sometimes leading to incorrect results, as a number of similar recent questions emphasise:

1. [Conflicting who/whom usage rules in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384974/conflicting-who-whom-usage-rules-in-a-sentence)
2. [The use of "whoever" or "whomever" in complex sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400028/the-use-of-whoever-or-whomever-in-complex-sentence)

In the first example of such confusion the OP was not able to clarify the situation using the substitution rule and in the second, the OP had explained in comments that using the substitution rule led to a false 'whom' where 'who' is to be used. That shows the need for some sort of a simple algorithm that would help non-native speakers of English correctly choose who/whom for almost any situation, especially when the sentence has multiple subjects, objects, verbs and clauses.

I am still working on this very interesting topic but what I have managed to grasp is the following;

> 'who' is a subject pronoun and 'whom' is an object pronoun

as explained by Professor Malcolm Gibson's [article](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/whom.html) *Who is correct? Yes, though it may depend on whom you ask!* which I referenced in two of my answers on ELU regarding *who/whom*: therefore an example of a practical approach that I would suggest at present would be

> 1. Look at the verb that requires *who/whom*:
>      if the verb needs a subject pronoun, select ‘who’.
>      If the verb does *not* need a subject pronoun, see whether it is a transitive or an intransitive verb.
> 2. If it is a transitive verb, it needs an object pronoun: so select ‘whom’
> 3. If it is an intransitive verb or a linking verb, it does not need an object pronoun: so select ‘who’.
> 4. In more complex sentences having multiple verbs, the choice of who/whom depends on whether the *clause as a whole* takes a subject pronoun or an object pronoun.

---

**Appendix: Explanatory notes**

The so-called ‘simple substitution rule’ given in earlier answers works especially well in simple sentences, as does my own method highlighted above. Problems arise when the sentence does not obviously require a subject pronoun, and the concerned verb is moreover not obviously transitive, making it difficult to decide whether it needs an object pronoun.

As @Peter Shor pointed out elsewhere in comments, problems also arise when the sentence has *more than one verb*, in which case the problem is how to decide which verb ‘who/whom’ would apply to: to determine which, some element of contextual reading and deconstruction might be required.

> Example: “These are the men **who** they believe conspired to rob a bank.” – Peter Shor

Decoding this sentence, “what do they believe?” – *“they believe (that) these men conspired to rob a bank.”*

*Whom* is not to be used after ‘these are the men’ because the object of the transitive verb ‘believe’ is not ‘these men’ but the [object clause](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/object-clause), “these men conspired to rob a bank.”

Now it is notable that changing any verb other than 'believe' will not change the choice of who/whom: not even if a transitive verb like '(they) saw', which makes ‘these men’ its object, were to replace ‘conspired’; as in

> *they believe (that) they saw these men rob the bank:*
>
> these are the men **who** they believe they saw rob the bank.

Why not ‘whom’, since *they saw* these men? Aren't these the men *whom they saw* rob the bank? Not exactly, because they only 'believe' so – and the object of the verb ‘believe’ is again not ‘these men’ but the [object clause](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/object_clause) 'they saw these men rob the bank' – in short, ‘these men’ never being the object of ‘believe’, ‘whom’ is not to be selected here.

Modifying the use of ‘believe’ a little will, however, change the choice of who/whom:

> They believe these men to have conspired to rob the bank.

‘These men’ having finally become the object of ‘believe’,  ‘whom’ is now required here.

> These are the men (whom) they believe to have conspired to rob the bank.

Thus we might conclude, as @Andrew Leach suggested in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400197/please-suggest-a-simple-practical-approach-to-correctly-select-who-or-whom-f#comment950360_400197) here, that

> (4) in more complex sentences having multiple verbs, the choice of who/whom depends on whether the *clause as a whole* takes a subject pronoun or an object pronoun [paraphrase].

Expert members please evaluate this method and post comments suggesting corrections/improvements to the practical approach I have highlighted in this answer.

Comment: The part about adding in _saw_ is not correct: it **should** be _whom_ in that sentence: “These are the men whom they believe they saw rob the bank”. If you transform it into a main clause, you get “They believe they saw **them** rob the bank”, which has an object pronoun. When the whole sentence is turned into a relative clause, that object pronoun is extracted from its position within the embedded clause and placed at the head of the entire relative clause—but it retains its original function and underlying location.

Comment: Note that this is actually precisely the same, structurally speaking, as the version without _saw_: “These are the men who they believe robbed the bank” → “They believe **they** robbed the bank” (subject, _who_). The relative pronoun _who_ here is also extracted from within the embedded clause _(that) they robbed the bank_. It can get quite hard to keep track of with very complex sentences, but the choice of _who(m)_ always depends on the function of the referent in the underlying clause.

Comment: This is all a part of what is known as [_wh_-movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement), the function by which elements within a clause are moved to a different position either in the same clause or in a containing clause. In English, _wh_-fronting is the most common movement of this type, with a pronoun representing the element ending up at the head of whatever clause it ends up in.

Comment: *"I believe he **did** this"* -> *"You believe who **did** this?"* -> *"Who do you believe **did** this?"*. 
On the other hand, *"I believe him **to have done** this"* -> *"You believe whom **to have done** this?"* -> *"Whom do you believe **to have done** this?"*.

Comment: The substitution rule works fine, the difficulty is in decoding the sentence, not in the rule.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet many thanks for the detailed and constructive feedback, which was the main intention of posting this Q and A : somebody told me that both 'who' and 'whom' could be used with 'they believe they saw these men...' based on different lines of reasoning, so this sentence (which I am retaining as such for the moment) serves to emphasise the complexity and ambiguity of the who/whom rule for English learners.

Comment: @Ben says No to Politics very perceptive comment! Yes indeed everything lies in decoding the sentence. Which is why I need a simple method that learners can use for this purpose.

Comment: The rule for learners is simple: Just use "who". Nobody will care. Use of "whom" should be considered advanced, not to be contemplated until you can curse idiomatically. :-)

Comment: @Ben says no to Politics very true; and I use 'who' and 'whom' more or less correctly without thinking about it or applying any test or rule: but in many other cases, people like my friend, who are actually 'learners' if you consider their English expertise, find themselves in positions where their supervisors expect perfect grammar as in an 'advanced English' situation.

Comment: I thought the primary aim of the bounty was to see whether your solution stood up to the test. But despite getting some impressive, and authoritative feedback from users, you haven't "improved" (edited) your answer. Why is that?

Comment: @Mari-lou A the main reason is that the excellent feedback of Janus Bahs Jacquet, MAA and John Lawler goes in more or less the same direction, which is a good approach that involves 'finding the gap' and substituting the pronoun to see if it is a subject pronoun or an object pronoun -- whereas my answer follows a very different logic of analysing the verb itself to see if it is transitive or intransitive or a linking verb -- so I did learn much from their answers but do not really see a way to use that to improve my own answer. However their approach now seems a better option for the Learner!

Comment: OK, that makes sense.