# The phrase "belong to" in a question

Tags: verbs, questions, phrasal-verbs, pied-piping

Can we separate the words "belong" and "to" in a question like this?

> To what language family does English belong?

Comment: yes, what makes you think you wouldn't be able to?

Comment: I have googled it and I can only find it in very few examples. Would you say it is an old fashioned way of asking a question? Thanks for your answer by the way :-)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's old-fashioned, maybe slightly more formal.

Comment: [Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/how-are-the-interrogative-pronouns-who-whom-whose-which-and-what-used), while reinterpreting [belong] [to N] as verb + PP, does include the non-controversial examples: 
The object forms of the interrogative pronoun are used after a preposition. In informal and everyday usage, you can place the preposition at the end of the clause.
• _Who does this belong to?_           Informal //
• _To whom does this belong?_       [very]  Formal'

Comment: If you want a very simple way of thinking about this -- in the old days, it was considered bad style to end a sentence or question with a preposition, and so one had to move the "to" in your example to another place.  But nowadays it's rare to come across an objection to ending with a preposition ("What language family does English belong to?" ).  However, one may still move the preposition if one wishes to do so!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can (but see the bottom of the answer for why it doesn't matter). The process is called [Pied-piping](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299) in English syntax. It happens in *wh*-clauses, like questions or relative clauses, where a *wh*-word is normally moved to the beginning

- *Bill kicked **the ball**. ~ **What** did Bill kick? ~ the ball **which** Bill kicked*

Normally the *wh*-word is the subject or the object of the clause;
but in some cases it's the object of a preposition, like

- *He came **from that city***.  (prepositional phrase in original form)
- ***Which city** did he come **from***?  (stranded preposition = phrase separated)
- ***From which city** did he come?* (pied-piped preposition = phrase united)

In the two questions above (let's ignore [relative clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/401168/15299); pied-piping works the same there) there's a conflict. The original statement that the questions came from has a prepositional phrase that can get split apart by *wh*-movement, leaving a stranded preposition at the end;  **or** that phrase can get moved as a unit, with the *wh*-word already installed, by pied-piping.

However, that construction **does** require that the structure be analyzed by both the speaker and the addressee  beyond the major constituents, which is work, and takes training, of the sort that you get in good schools, and that bespeaks education and signals status, which is why it's considered "formal".

As far as the original question is concerned, *belong to* is not a phrasal verb, any more than *come from* is. It's just a preposition that's required by the verb to complete its usage here. But separating the preposition from the verb is not the issue. It's separating the preposition from its object; or not. The verb is just doing its thing.