# Usage of the phrase "to which" in this mathematical explanation

Tags: phrases, prepositions, pronouns, mathematics

I'm sure I am overthinking this, but I wanted to understand this explanation better (and in turn, be able to explain it to students better). Observe the following explanation of a *function* in mathematics:

[image]

> What it means to be a function *f* : *A* → *B* is this: *f* assigns to each element of *A* exactly one element of *B*. If *a* ∈ *A*, the notation *f* (*a*) denotes the element of *B* to which *a* is assigned by *f*.

I am unfamiliar with the usage of the phrase **to which** in the second sentence. when the author uses this phrase do they mean that the element `a` is assigned the element `f(a)` by `f` (in slightly different wording)?

Comment: Ask yourself this: what does "which" (not "to which") refer to?

Comment: @BillJ - In that case I would assume "which" refers to the element *a* previously mentioned at the beginning of the sentence? :)

Comment: @TaylorRendon No, it refers to _the element of B_, the noun phrase that precedes it, which is called its Antecedent. The _to_ originated in the phrase _assigned to_, and got moved to the front because _which_ is its object. An equivalent way of saying it is _the element of B which_ a _is assigned by_ f _to_. That's pretty clunky, too, due to the passive _is assigned to by_ f. If you want to look this up, the key phrase is ["pied-piping"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/589666/15299). Honest.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Just so I understand your explanation and answer what I have asked above: according to what you've written, does this imply the author means that *a* is assigned the element *f(a)* (the element of *B*) by *f*? Thank you for your time, as well.

Comment: Yes. It would have been easier if the author had used the active, thus making _f_'s value the focus of the sentence. The passive puts it at the end, for unknown reasons.

Comment: I passed A-level maths (a long time ago, admittedly), but I must say I find OP's text "impenetrable", to say the least! So I'm guessing, but I suspect that last part is a clumsy way of saying *...f(a) is the element of B to which f assigns the value a*. And I'm sure there are far less verbose ways of saying the same thing, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where mathematics is assisted by precise English usage. I will tease it apart and try to illustrate with a specific example.

*A* is a set of elements.
*B* is a second set of elements.
*f*  is the name of a function that maps each element in *A* onto one of the elements in *B*.

In other words,  *f*  is the name of a defined operation by which we relate all elements of *A* to some (not necessarily all) of the elements of *B*.

Consider a simple example. I put all the elements as bold:

Let’s imagine *A* is the set {**1, 2, 3, 4**} and *B* is the set of all positive integers {**1, 2, 3, 4**, …}.

Now imagine  *f*  to be a function that maps any number onto its square.

So applying  *f*  to the set *A* {**1, 2, 3, 4**} → {**1, 4, 9, 16**}.

{**1, 4, 9, 16**} is a subset of *B*, and therefore every element of *A* is mapped to exactly one element of *B*.

Now consider the prose.

If *a* is a member of the set *A*, the operation *f* (*a*) means “map *a* to the corresponding element of *B*”.

In my example we would have  *f* (**2**) → **4**.
**4** is therefore the element of B referred to by  *f* (**2**).

Or, to put it as in your example, **4** is the element of *B* to which **2** is assigned by  *f*.

In an annotated version of the same statement:
**4** [an element in *B*] is the element of *B* to which [referring to the relevant element in *B*]  **2** [an element in *A*] is assigned by  *f*  [the mapping of a number to its square].

It may help if I illustrate the example with a picture:

[image]

Comment: @justin Many thanks for tidying. I had to leave in a hurry.

Comment: I cleaned it up some more :)

Comment: @justin Looks good. Thanks