# Is who or whom correct in the following situation?

Tags: grammar, whom, who

The sentence is as follows: "Isn't it evident who/whom they have in mind for the position?"

Depending on how you try to reword it to figure it out, the answer seems different.

--Is it not evident that he is the one they have in mind for the position? (This seems to be a case for "who" here.)

--Is it not evident that they have him in mind for the new position? (This seems to be a case for "whom" here.)

Should it be who or whom? Why?

Comment: When tweaking a sentence to figure out if it's _who_ or _whom_, you're supposed to reword minimally. Your first rewording quite significantly changes the sentence's structure, even accounting for the fact that it's derived from a question. You may take a look at [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400197/how-do-i-choose-between-who-or-whom-when-the-subject-pronoun-is-unclear) Q&A, and also consider looking at [this ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom).

Comment: *Isn't it evident they have him in mind for the position?*

Comment: There are those who would argue for the objective case ('whom') here on established grammatical grounds, but I'd say that the use of 'who' in this case (1) is nowadays more common and (2) sounds less rarefied/highfalutin. Idiomaticity trumps traditional grammatical usage where a contest arises, and eventually dictates changed grammaticality. 'Whom' except directly after a preposition is heading for moribund.